# Prove Unique Linear Tranformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that for any pair of linear transformations T : U$\rightarrow$V , S : W$\rightarrow$V, there is a unique linear transformation

R:U$\times$W$\rightarrow$V such that for u$\in$U and w$\in$W we have R((u,w)) = T(u) + S(w)

My attempt:

Uniqueness:  let $R_1$((u,w)) = T(u) + S(w) and $R_2$((u,w)) = T(a) + S(b)

Hence $R_1 - R_2$ = $R((0,0)) = 0 = T(u-a)+S(w-b)$

My problem is how would I show that $T(u-a)+S(w-b)$ = $0$ iff u=a and w=b or is there another way to view this problem that would be better ?

Answer (score 1):

If your linear transformation is defined as $$R((u,w)) = T(u) + S(w),$$ then, if we assume that there is another linear transformation $$\tilde R((u,w))= T(u) + S(w)$$
that maps $(u,w) \mapsto T(u) + S(w)$ presicely as $R$ does, it obviously holds that

$$R = \tilde R$$ for all $(u,w) \in U\times W$.